# Custom Add Applications Link isn't working

Tags: java, themes, liferay, velocity

i want to add a custom Add Application Link to my Liferay Theme.

This is what i have in the template (portlet_normal.vm):

```
            #if($show_add_content)
              <a href="javascript:$add_content_url" id="addApplications">$add_content_text</a>
              <a href="javascript:$layout_url" id="layoutTemplates">$layout_text</a>
            #end
```

and this is what I got on the page:

```
<a href="javascript:Liferay.LayoutConfiguration.toggle('87');" id="addApplications">Add   Application</a> 
<a href="javascript:Liferay.LayoutConfiguration.showTemplates();" id="layoutTemplates">Layout Template</a>
```

The Layoutbutton is working as expected, but the Add Applications portlet is'nt loaded.

I think about missing libs/includes? Has anyone an idea?

Comment: No idea, but +1 to anyone who has to deal with liferay...

Comment: @cwallenpoole it's nice, if you know where you have to punch it... but sometimes it punches back very hard^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- What version are you using? (always helps when trying to reproduce)
- Is "portlet_normal.vm" a typo in the question or is this the file that you created? It needs to be portal_normal.vm
- What else did you change in your installation? Other changes to the vm file? properties file changes with relation to javascript files?
- Have you tried a different browser?
- Is the id (given in the 'a' element) unique?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the solution in 
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Link+to+Dockbar

The addApplication works for me. However the layout template link didn't work.